# Descendants within descendants in LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm struggling to navigate to my 'user' element in my XML; I want a set of users so I can then extract username details. My LINQ query is as follows and always returns 0 for the count (though is not null)

```
var xApprovers = from d in doc.Root.Descendants("document_version")
                               .Elements("stages")
                               .Elements("stage")
                               .Elements("user")
                               .Elements("approver_list")
                               .Elements("approver")
                               .Elements("user")
                 where d.Element("docVersionID").Value == vId
                 select d;
```

My XML source is:

```
<Root>
<document_version>
    <version_number>1</version_number>
    <version_comments></version_comments>
    <creation_date>2011-12-20 09:20:42.877</creation_date>
    <docVersionID>00002_0000000453</docVersionID>
    <pageno>-1</pageno>
    <author>
      <user>
        <userID>00002_0000000001</userID>
        <login>ACRE_ROBOT</login>
        <lastname>ROBOT</lastname>
        <firstname>ACRE</firstname>
        <email>richardtaylor@vcg-kestrel.com</email>
      </user>
    </author>
    <document_approval_cycle_code>0</document_approval_cycle_code>
    <document_approval_cycle_status>Not Started</document_approval_cycle_status>
    <stage_index>1</stage_index>
    <stages>
      <stage>
        <stage_id>00002_0000001017</stage_id>
        <name></name>
        <index>1</index>
        <conditional_approval>1</conditional_approval>
        <upon_rejection_code>0</upon_rejection_code>
        <stage_approval_cycle_code>0</stage_approval_cycle_code>
        <stage_approval_cycle_status>Not Started</stage_approval_cycle_status>
        <stage_approval_code>00001_0000000002</stage_approval_code>
        <stage_approval_status>Pending</stage_approval_status>
        <approver_list>
          <approver>
            <user>
              <userID>00002_0000000011</userID>
              <login>DEVAPP78@APPROVER.COM</login>
              <lastname>App 78</lastname>
              <firstname>Dev</firstname>
              <email>DevApp78@approver.com</email>
            </user>
            <approval_action />
          </approver>
          <approver>
            <user>
              <userID>00002_0000000010</userID>
              <login>DEVAPP77@APPROVER.COM</login>
              <lastname>App 77</lastname>
              <firstname>Dev</firstname>
              <email>DevApp77@approver.com</email>
            </user>
            <approval_action />
          </approver>
        </approver_list>
      </stage>
    </stages>
    <approvals></approvals>
</document_version>
</Root>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you need all `users` of a `document_version` by `docVersionID` given, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had two problems, you had an extra .Elements("user") which wasn't necessary

You also were trying to apply the where clause to the wrong element

Here's the corrected LINQ which returns the result in the same IEnumerable<XElement> as your original

```
  var xGood = from docVersion in doc.Root.Descendants( "document_version" )
              where docVersion.Element("docVersionID").Value == vId
              from d in docVersion.Elements( "stages" )
                                  .Elements( "stage" )
                                  .Elements( "approver_list" )
                                  .Elements( "approver" )
                                  .Elements( "user" )
              select d;
```

The notable difference between this LINQ and abatishchev's is that this would support multiple document_version nodes in a single xml document

Comment: Thank you Merick, that's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

you have an extra user selection. Try

```
var xApprovers = from d in doc.Root
                              .Descendants("document_version")
                 where d.Element("docVersionID").Value == vId
                 select d.Elements("stages")
                              .Elements("stage")
                              .Elements("approver_list")
                              .Elements("approver")
                              .Elements("user");
```

Comment: If I take away the where statement it works, but with it does not... any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: Now it's same as my :) But both returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>`, aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just this:

```
from d in doc.Root.Descendants("document_version")
where d.Element("docVersionID").Value == vId
select d.Elements("stages")
        .Elements("stage")
        .Elements("approver_list")
        .Elements("approver")
        .Elements("user");
```

or

```
doc.Root
   .Descendants("document_version")
   .SingleOrDefault(d => d.Element("docVersionID").Value == vId).Elements("stages") // sic!
   .Elements("stage")
   .Elements("approver_list")
   .Elements("approver")
   .Elements("user");
```

---

Or run XPath:

```
(IEnumerable)doc.XPathEvaluate(String.Format("Root/document_version/docVersionID[text()='{0}']/../stages/stage/approver_list/approver/user", vId));
```

Comment: Your linq would be slightly different returning an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> rather than an IEnumerable<string> like the original

Comment: @Merick: `SingleOrDefault()` should fix that

Comment: @Merick: btw, OP's query returns `IEnumerable<XElement>` :)

Comment: SingleOrDefault limits the xml to one document_version which might not be correct

Comment: @Merick: I think that's unique ID among the document. OP can proof me wrong.